# Deploy correctly SPFx v1.4.1 package in SharePoint server 2019 using gulp

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, 2019, solution-deployment, sharepoint-framework

I would like to know how to deploy correctly SPFx package in SharePoint Server 2019 on-premise using gulp and sppkg.

It seems that SharePoint server doesn't not work like SharePoint online and it doesn't support Office 365 public CDN.

Here, you can find my **package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "extension-spfx-2019",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/decorators": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-dialog": "~1.4.0",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/graph": "^1.2.8",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^5.135.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules": "1.4.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please refer https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/spfx-with-sharepoint-2019/ which is showing the steps to create & deploy the SPFx webpart in SharePoint 2019.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following document to deploy spfx v 1.4.1 package in sharepoint server 2019
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved.